# Open Editor option is not visible for me in the Living Doc view in Azure Devops. Can anyone shed light on what am I missing here?

Tags: azure-devops, bdd, specflow

Open Editor option is not visible for me in the Living Doc view in Azure Devops. The SpecflowProject is present in the Azure Repos with the Build setup configured for test assembly in one branch and Feature Folder in other as the Generator Source.

Can anyone tell where I am going wrong with the setup?

[image]

Comment: Hi, Could you share some screenshot of the error page? In addition the Living Doc view is extension tab or others?

Comment: Yes sure. The question is for the Specflow+Livingdoc tab in Azure Devops>>Project>>Overview section.

Comment: I have embedded the link to the image in the original post itself.

Comment: The "open in editor" button in LivingDoc only supports Azure Repos Git and TFVS, so if your project uses a git repository hosted somewhere else (outside of Azure Devops) the button is not visible. If your project uses Azure Repos please open a support ticket here: https://support.specflow.org/hc/en-us/requests/new

Comment: @AshwiniKumari did you get this resolved?  We have the same issue.

Comment: Same issue, any update on this? @SgtWilko